Unable to boot using Grub, instead getting thrown into the grub command shell
I am currently trying to find a fix for the above described problem and while doing so have been unable to find an answer as seemingly none of the solutions work, I have tried every posted answer on multiple threads:

GRUB starts in command line after reboot
grub error: you need to load kernel first
How to Rescue a Non-booting GRUB 2 on Linux

None of these solutions have worked and I am tired and exhausted after having this problem on both my machines after trying to use grub with arch. I am no longer able boot into my arch instance due to me wiping the drive the installation medium was on please help me with this since I desperatly need to get it fixed. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Are you getting grub> or grub rescue> ? UEFI or BIOS install? What brand/model system? What version of Linux? May be best to see details of your configuration: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

I am getting grub>, UEFI custom one I built myself with a gigabyte motherboard B650 Gaming X, arch linux the newest I am gonna try to get  the bootinfo asap

Not sure about Boot-Repair & Arch. I know it works with most Linux. You may need ot install a few supporting libraries or manually mount partitions before running report.

I'd love to try that tmr but for the past 3 hours or so I have tried multiple software to write to my USB with my laptop and sadly none of them work else I could have just installed rEfindthrough chroot

You should always be able to chroot into your install from a live installer. UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380
chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088

Huh alr I will try writing the ubuntu iso image then tmr since I have been unable to write the arch image

Thanks to you I found out it was not my writer causing the problem but a bad usb slot, after which not only ubuntu's iso but also arch's install medium worked I just installed rEfind after that and now I can use my machine again but sadly I still couldn't find a solution to the grub issue
